# How can I store a value from a malloc'd pointer so when I free it I can still return the value it initially held?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I have a value being returned from a function which is a pointer to a malloc'd address which stores a string value. That string value is what I want to return. But to prevent leaks I need to free that same address, which in turn makes me lose the value I want to return.

I tried creating a `tmp` pointer as work around but I assume I'm doing something very wrong.
Here's a little code snippet, where `line` is what needs to be free'd, but also its value needs to be returned.

```c
char *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    static char *storage;
    char *buffer;
    char *line;
    char *tmp;

    tmp = NULL;
    line = NULL;
    if (!fd || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0)
        return (NULL);

    read_to_buffer(fd, &buffer, &storage);
    free(buffer);

    tmp = line;
    line = extract_line(storage); // extract_line() returns a malloc'd pointer.
    free(&tmp);
    return (line);
}
```

Comment: If I'm understating you correctly, you can't - you have to return the malloc'd (unfreed) pointer.

Comment: After you `free` a pointer you cannot dereference it (i.e. access what it is/was pointing to) - that's UB (undefined behavior).

Comment: Making a `tmp` variable changes nothing. The answer is.... you can't do what you are trying

Comment: Is there an upper limit for line length ?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Currently it's causing leaks if I just return as is, so I assume that's an issue, right?

Comment: You should `free` after you are done using it

Comment: OT: Shouldn't there be a `free(storage);` in the code?

Comment: @SupportUkraine There's another function elsewhere which handles the storage memory. So far that seems not to cause leaks.

Comment: Running your program under valgrind will show you all the memory leaks.

Comment: You're awfully close to reinventing [POSIX `getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), and there are lots of open-source implementations of that available for non-POSIX platforms.

Comment: "how can I have my cake and eat it"

Comment: @PaulHankin You divide the cake in half. Eat one part. Then you still have one cake left. Unfortunately, the committee forgot to standardize `free_half()`

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp = line;
line = extract_line(storage); // extract_line() returns a malloc'd pointer.
free(&tmp);
return (line);
```

In the above code, both `tmp` and `line` are pointing to the same memory. So when `tmp` is freed, essentially the memory pointed to by `line` is also freed. And any attempt to use `tmp` after `line` has been freed will lead to undefined behaviour.

From C11, Memory Management Functions:

`free()`:

> ....Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned
> by a memory management function, or **if the space has been deallocated
> by a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined.**

Re:

> But to prevent leaks I need to free that same address, which in turn
> makes me lose the value I want to return.

C does not allow you to use memory after it has been freed. There's no need to `free()` the memory in this function if you have to return it. It will only ever result in a memory leak if you forgot to `free()` the memory (in the calling function) once you're done with it.

> where line is what needs to be free'd, but also its value needs to be
> returned.

If the memory pointed to by `line` is required for further processing, then there's no *need* for it to be freed in the function `get_next_line`.

Aside: `free(&tmp);` should be `free (tmp);`. And the parentheses after the `return` statements are redundant.

Comment: "That doesn't seem to be a valid requirement." The requirement (i.e. avoid returning dynamic allocated memory of variable size) is indeed valid. That it can't be done in C is another story.

Comment: @Support Ukraine I disagree. The requirement is two-fold, i.e. *"where line is what needs to be free'd, but also its value needs to be returned.*" --> the memory should be freed in the called function as well as returned to the calling function after being freed.

Comment: There are many programming languages that allows that. It's not doable in C but that doesn't make the requirement bad. Just the choice of language as it can't be done in C.

Comment: @ If that's the case, I relinquish mine.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Under the hood, Java for example does the dynamic allocation and free for you - C just doesn't do much hand-holding.  "It can be done" only because the management of dynamic memory is done for you.  And yeah, if you need that C is the wrong language for you to be using.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Fully agree. I assume/think that any language capable of dealing with objects of variable size uses dynamical memory allocation somewhere deep down. The difference is whether it's exposed to the programmer. In C it always is... In C++ it's - for some object types - handled without the programmer having to do anything. In other words: If you have a hard requirement in relation to handling of memory allocation, you need to go for a language that supports it.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good (better) idea to provide a buffer, instead of allocating a buffer and returning it. If you write a function and that function returns an allocated buffer, you can't be sure, that the buffer will be freed.

Therefore, the function should accept a buffer (and its size) and use that buffer instead. The specification could allow to pass a `NULL` pointer to let the function allocate a buffer (which has to be freed by the user via a specified function, e.g. `free`).

e.g.

```
//instead
char* get_next_line(int fd);

//do
char* get_next_line(int fd, char *dst, int dst_len);
```

The second version also has the advantage to reuse a single buffer, instead of an allocation at each and every call.

"*A clever person solves a problem. A wise person avoids it.*"
Albert Einstein

Comment: @SupportUkraine If the specification allows it, pass a `NULL` pointer as argument to let the function allocate a buffer of right size. Better reuse a buffer, instead of permanent allocation. Eceptions shouldn't be the rule.

Comment: @SupportUkraine You're missing the point. Do not allocate if it is not necessary. Allocate if desired. Let the user decide, not the function.

Comment: Well... IMO the answer is somewhat unclear: I read "It is always a good (better) idea to provide a buffer, instead of allocating a buffer and returning it." as "Never let a function allocate memory". But then it says "The specification could allow to pass a NULL pointer to let the function allocate a buffer" which is contradicting as this actually means "Let the function allocate memory and return a pointer" Further: "If you write a function and that function returns an allocated buffer, you can't be sure, that the buffer will be freed." isn't really handled by option 2. So also contradicting

Comment: @SupportUkraine Oh boy, really? What you understand of my words, doesn't bind me. In the previous comments, i gave perfectly good reasons. Instead of providing arguments, you're trying to play a word game?

Comment: @SupportUkraine Instead of playing word games, tell us how to avoid the OP's problem and how to enable buffer reuse with your approach? With your proposal, you're shifting the problem upwards but neither avoiding it nor give a good alternative solution. So, please, let us stop it right here.